# how to import delimited data into mysql in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This is a sample of the data im working with

```
24701||37.279788||-81.229023||WV||BLUEFIELD||MERCER
```

as you can see its double pipe delimited.
phpmyadmin is asking me for the following

```
Fields Terminated By  
Fields Enclosed By    
Fields Escaped By  
Lines Terminated By
```

what do i put to correctly import my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysqlimport works with --fields-terminated-by="||"

```
Fields Terminated By ||
```

Looks like PHPMyAdmin doesn't. Then you have to do a replace, but be careful that you aren't messing with your data (ie, if you replace || for , be sure there are no further , characters in the original)

Comment: it errors: Invalid parameter for CSV import: Fields terminated by

Comment: That looks like a bug in phpmyadmin... :/ mysqlimport, the commandline tool works perfectly using --fields-terminated-by="||"

Answer (score 11):

I found this very useful and maybe this can help others.

In the Format-Specific Options section you can set the values as follows:

Columns separated with: ***You can choose , or \t for tab delimited***

Columns enclosed with: ***You can leave this empty but if even one column is enclosed in " then enter " (quotes)***

Columns escaped with: **You have to enter \ (backslash)**

Lines terminated with: ***You can leave this auto***

Hope this helps

Comment: Tried using this and got the WSoD.

Answer (score 0):

Did a find/replace in notepad++ of || and replaced it with comma so the data read

```
24701,37.279788,-81.229023,WV,BLUEFIELD,MERCER
```

Then filled in the following:

```
Fields Terminated By ,
Fields Enclosed By 
Fields Escaped By \
Lines Terminated By auto
```

worked great