# HOWTO insert TXT content to table

Tags: mysql, sql, text, import, phpmyadmin

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `trxppl` (
  `col1` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `col2` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `col3` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `col4` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `col5` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `col6` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `col7` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col8` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `col9` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `col10` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col11` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `col12` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col13` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col14` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col15` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col16` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col17` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col18` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col19` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col20` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `col21` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `col22` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

i want to import this data ( from text file ) with phpmyadmi
e.g. try.txt
that file have data :

2|MAIN ROOM|MAIN ROOM FAMILY|HOUSE|HOME|BIKERS|235235234|BUDI1|2015-07-20 14:35:56|234324|DATA|50|106.821210|-6.1956736|234234|01048|45792|24324324|1||2015-07-20||0

2|MAIN ROOM|MAIN ROOM FAMILY|HOUSE|HOME|BIKERS|235235234|JOKO12|2015-07-15 16:08:34|23432423|DATA|100|106.831368|-6.1793116|234234|01019|47478|234234|1||2015-07-15||1

---

can anyone help me to solve this ?

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: i just dont know how to put that data, when i tried some tips from google search, it said error in various error number that i cant resolve it

Comment: Describe what you did and post the error. By InnoDB I assume this is MySQL? I have added the tag for you. Now you need to describe the problem properly.

Comment: i use win. 81 + xampp and build-in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin executes SQL, and it can executes a CSV (comma separated fields). Your data is an string with a `|` separating fields.You need to convert first this string to an SQL or CSV valid file (you can use PHP or you can make it handmaded). Then you can import to phpMyAdmin

Comment: You need to build an script (you can use your favourite language: PHP, Java, .NET, etc) to convert your string in a valid CSV or SQL file. Is simplest if you made a CSV (comma separated fields). You need to read first each line, and inside each line you need to separate fields with the pattern `|` and you obtain an array of fields of each line.

Comment: what keyword on google that i must search ? since the ' | ' is ignored on google search engine

Comment: You don't need to search a vertical bar on google to this. Search about read file and convert to csv or something similar. Is better if you know how to develop with the language that you will use. If you don't know how to programming it will be very difficult to achieve

Comment: this problem i found when i try to import my data to texty format and i want try to import it

Comment: When you export a database, is better if you made in a standard language, like SQL. phpMyAdmin exports your database in this format. But I don't know how to help you now, you need to convert this text file to a phpMyAdmin compatible source, and now it doesn't.

Comment: According to this, it is not necessary to change the delimiter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302046/how-to-import-delimited-data-into-mysql-in-phpmyadmin

Comment: ( looking up the link )

Answer (score 0):

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/try.txt' INTO TABLE table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (field1,field2,field3);

Try it like this with you data